# Como convertir valor de celda de datagridview en c#

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo una pequeño programa, pero necesito cambiar el tipo de dato que hay en la celda del datagridview.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Percepciones");
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Percepciones");

                    dt.Columns.Add("Concepto");
                    dt.Columns.Add("Monto", typeof(Double));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Empleado", typeof(Int32));
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DgvNomina.Rows)
                    {
                        if(row.Cells["Sueldo"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
                        {
                            DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
                            r["Concepto"] = "Sueldo Neto";
                            r["Monto"] = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Sueldo"].Value);//aqui me muestra el error
                            r["Empleado"] = row.Cells["ID"].Value;
                            dt.Rows.Add(r);
                        }
                    }

                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

El datagridview lo recorro, y le pongo que el valor de la columna "Sueldo" me lo cambie a tipo Double, en el datagrid lo muestro con formato moneda, ya he intentado, convertirlo pero me sigue mostrando el siguiente error.

> System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'

Comment: Por pantalla, todo es un string... formateado.. pero un string...

Comment: Pero en la celda "ID" no me da ese error

Comment: no lo estas convirtiendo... por eso.. en que formato esta por pantalla? puede ser un problema de puntos y comas...

Comment: En el datagrid lo muestro con formato de moneda

Comment: si esta con formato de moneda, o sea tiene un signo $ (o lo que sea) adelante, entonces no podes transformalo a doble, porque eso agarra el string completo y trata de convertirlo. Tenes que sacarle todos los signos que no sean numero antes de hacer la transformacion....

Comment: igual si es un monto deberia ser decimal la variable.. y en la base de datos no se como lo tengas, pero no hay dobles en la db...

Comment: ese dato no lo guardo, lo calculo con otros metodos, y me regresa un valor tipo double, y en el datagrid solo le pongo el formato moneda asi: valor.ToString("C2");

Comment: y no podes transformar un string en formato moneda a un double... tenes que sacarle todo lo que no es numerico.. se entiende eso?

Comment: Si, ya pude hacerlo, gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: ok.. agrega una respuesta entonces...

Answer (score 0):

Después de mucho intentar al fin pude cambiar el tipo de dato usando CultureInfo.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Percepciones");
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Percepciones");

                dt.Columns.Add("Concepto");
                dt.Columns.Add("Monto", typeof(Double));
                dt.Columns.Add("Empleado", typeof(Int32));
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DgvNomina.Rows)
                {
                    if(row.Cells["Sueldo"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
                    {
                        DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
                        r["Concepto"] = "Sueldo Neto";
                        Double monto = Double.Parse(row.Cells["Sueldo"].Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
                            r["Monto"] = monto;
                        r["Empleado"] = row.Cells["ID"].Value;
                        dt.Rows.Add(r);
                    }
                }

                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```